# PDFMake loop using canvas data doesn't keep correct order

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, pdf-generation

I am using the following code to render DOM elements as canvas data and then make a PDF with them.

I have had to create a loop for this because if it was all one image it is impossible to correctly place the data over multiple pages.

```
$scope.pdfMaker = function() {

    var content = [];

    var pdfElement = document.getElementsByClassName("pdfElement");
    for (var i = pdfElement.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        html2canvas(pdfElement[i], {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {

                var data = canvas.toDataURL();

                content.push({
                    image: data,
                    width: 500,
                    margin: [0, 5]
                });
                console.log(canvas);
            }

        });
    }
    var docDefinition = {
        content: content
    };

    setTimeout(function() {
        pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download("Score_Details.pdf");
    }, 10000);

}
```

Issues:

1. I have that nasty 10 second timeout to allow time for processing, how can I restructure my code to allow the PDF to be made after all canvas data has been performed.
2. My canvas elements are becoming mixed up when they are converted, the correct order is essential. How can I maintain the order of the DOM elements?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that html2canvas returns a promise:

```
$scope.pdfMaker = function() {

    var promises = [];
    var pdfElements = document.getElementsByClassName("pdfElement");

    for (var i = 0; i < pdfElements.length; i++) {
        promises.push(
            html2canvas(pdfElements[i]).then(function(canvas) {
                console.log('finished one!');
                return {
                    image: canvas.toDataURL(),
                    width: 500,
                    margin: [0, 5]
                };
            })
        );
    }

    console.log('done calling');
    $q.all(promises).then(function(content) {
        console.log('all done');
        pdfMake.createPdf({ content: content }).download("Score_Details.pdf");
        console.log('download one');
    }, function(err) {
        console.error(err);
    })

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get your code to work just requires a few mods.

The problem from your description is that the rendering time for html2canvas varies so that they come in an undetermined order. If you make the code inside the for loop a function and pass the index to it, the function will close over the argument variable, you can use that index in the onrendered callback because (that will also close over the index) to place the rendered html in the correct position of the content array.

To know when you have completed all the rendering and can convert to pdf, keep a count of the number of html2canvas renderer you have started. When the onrendered callback is called reduce the count by one. When the count is zero you know all the documents have been rendered so you can then call createPdf.

Below are the changes

```
$scope.pdfMaker = function() {
    var i,pdfElement,content,count,docDefinition;
    function makeCanvas(index){ // closure ensures that index is unique inside this function.
        count += 1; // count the new render request
        html2canvas(pdfElement[index], {
            onrendered: function(canvas) { // this function closes over index
                content[index] = {  // add the canvas content to the correct index
                    image: canvas.toDataURL(),
                    width: 500,
                    margin: [0, 5]
                };
                count -= 1; // reduce count
                if(count === 0){ // is count 0, if so then all done
                     // render the pdf and download
                    pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download("Score_Details.pdf");
                }
            }
        });        
    }
    // get elements
    pdfElement = document.getElementsByClassName("pdfElement");
    content = []; // create content array
    count = 0; // set render request counter
    docDefinition = {content: content}; //
    for (i = pdfElement.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { //do the loop thing
        makeCanvas(i);  // call the makeCanvas function with the index
    }

}
```

The only thing I was not sure of was the order you wanted the pdfElements to appear. The changes will place  the rendered content into the content array in the same order as `document.getElementsByClassName("pdfElement");` gets them.

If you want the documents in the revers order call content.reverse() when the count is back to zero and you are ready to create the pdf.

Closure is a very powerful feature of Javascript. If you are unsure of how closure works then a review is well worth the time.

[MDN closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) is as good a place as any to start and there are plenty of resources on the net to learn from.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to write this, I have a method that works a bit quicker that I will add as an answer now. cheers!

Comment: @Taylorsuk pls can you add the code in comment section for your method